# Access Logic Apps behind private endpoint from Power Automate/ Power Apps

Tags: azure, power-automate, azure-logic-app-standard

I know there is capability to call logic app from power automate by exporting the logic app as custom connector - Logic app needs to be under the consumption tier having its inbound IP public

Now the issue I face is that from the security requirements I have, I need to secure my logic app inbound endpoint. I can do this by using the standard tier and creating a private endpoint for my inbound traffic of my logic app.

When this is done, I can't export my logic app as custom connector anymore and I do not know how to make it available privately from my power platform environment using power automate for instance.

So to summarize, is it possible to call a logic app resource behind a private endpoint from power automate.

Thank you in advance for any support here.
Regards,
Marc.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked for an answer to that question myself and found your post.
From an old article, I can only find the solution to build your own custom connector in Power Platform that sends HTTPS queries over a data gateway:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premise-apis/

The default connector of Azure Automation doesn't support connection over a data gateway. Probably also Logic Apps.

This also means to me that Azure Automation still needs to stay public for us, too much customization.

Cheers,
Tobi